# Entity inheritance "Attempt to add id property private ...but already have property private"

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I got this error:

> org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Attempt to
>   add id property private java.lang.String
>   **com.example.estrans.domain.entities.bookshop.Entity.id** but already
>   have property private java.lang.String
>   **com.example.estrans.domain.entities.bookshop.Book.bookId** registered as
>   id. Check your mapping configuration!

When trying to use `spring-data` the `Book` entity that inherits form `Entity`. The `Entity` tries to cover all of the common functionalities from all potential specific entities.

**Entity**

```
@Getter
public class Entity {

    @Id
    private String id;

    public IndexQuery getIndexQuery(){
        return new IndexQueryBuilder().withId(this.getId()).withObject(this).build();
    }

}
```

**Book**

```
 @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Builder
    @Document(indexName = "bookshop", type = "book", shards = 1, replicas = 0, refreshInterval = "-1")
    public class Book extends Entity {

        @Id
        private String bookId;

        @Field(type = FieldType.String, store = true)
        private String title;
}
```

- How can I handle the inheritance while persiting only the concrete `Book` entity not the general `Entity`?

EDIT
Take a look at the discusion with `@builder` inheritance support https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/853

Comment: Entity should be annotated with MappedSuperclass, not Entity. And of course, since it already defined an ID, the subclasses should not define one.

Comment: Are you trying to use this class as JPA entity and Elasticsearch document?

Comment: I want to make it a ES doc but wanted the method not to be considered in the aspect of ES persistence.

Comment: You can't have two ids in one document or two properties marked with `@Id` annotation.  Removed the bookId in order for your document to use the id from your `Entity` class.  Marked the `getIndexQuery()` method from your `Entity` class with `@JsonIgnore` so it will not be part of the document when it is indexed.  I think this is related to your question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38804379/indexqueyrbuilder-method-inside-entity-class-results-in-failed-to-index-the-doc.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. Additionally one must consider the `lombok` lack of support for inheritance with the `@Builder`. A workaround is here [https://reinhard.codes/2015/09/16/lomboks-builder-annotation-and-inheritance/]