# IndexQueryBuilder method inside entity class results in "failed to index the document [id: 1]"

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I got this error:

> org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed
>   to index the document [id: 1]
>
> at
>   org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.prepareIndex(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:1028)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.index(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:525)
>   ...

Every time that I put inside my entity `Book` class a `getIndexQuery` method. So it look like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Document(indexName = "bookshop", type = "book", shards = 1, replicas = 0, refreshInterval = "-1")
public class Book  {

    @Id
    private String bookId;

    @Field(type = FieldType.String, store = true)
    private String title;

    public IndexQuery getIndexQuery(){
        return new IndexQueryBuilder().withId(this.getBookId()).withObject(this).build();
    }

}
```

The error occurs even when I do not use this method anyware in my code.
How can I put this method inside my entity class without it messing with the enitties schema (becouse that is what I assume what is wrong)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@JsonIgnore.`

```
@JsonIgnore
public IndexQuery getIndexQuery(){
    return new IndexQueryBuilder().withId(this.getBookId()).withObject(this).build();
}
```

`com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore` is from `jackson-core-2.8.1.jar` or add this dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```